# Solve $3^{x+2}\cdot4^{-(x+3)}+3^{x+4}\cdot4^{-(x+3)} = \frac{40}{9}$

Tags: logarithms

Can someone point me in the right direction how to solve this?

$3^{x+2}\cdot4^{-(x+3)}+3^{x+4}\cdot4^{-(x+3)} = \frac{40}{9}$

I guess I have to get to logarithms of the same base. But how? What principle should I use here?
Thx

Comment: Hint: factor out the fours and threes, its much easier then.

Comment: $3^{x+4}=3^{2}\cdot 3^{x+2}$

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$3^{ x+2 }\cdot 4^{ -(x+3) }+3^{ x+4 }\cdot 4^{ -(x+3) }=\frac { 40 }{ 9 } \\ { 4 }^{ -\left( x+3 \right)  }{ 3 }^{ x+2 }\left( 1+9 \right) =\frac { 40 }{ 9 } \\ { 4 }^{ -\left( x+3 \right)  }{ 3 }^{ x+2 }=\frac { 4 }{ 9 } \\ { \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  }^{ x }\frac { 9 }{ 64 } =\frac { 4 }{ 9 } \\ { \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  }^{ x }={ \left( \frac { 4 }{ 3 }  \right)  }^{ 4 }\\ x=-4\\ \\ $$

Comment: dear downvoter can you explain it why?)

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but i believe he may have downvoted because you provided the solution when OP asked for guidance.

Comment: That transition from 3rd to 4th line is was I was missing. Thank you, sir!

Comment: you are welcome)

Answer (score 1):

Using $a^{-b}=\frac{1}{a^b}$, The equation can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{3^{x+2}}{4^{x+3}}+\frac{3^{x+4}}{4^{x+3}}=\frac{40}{9}$$
$$\implies \frac{9}{64}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x+\frac{81}{64}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x=\frac{40}{9}$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x=\frac{256}{81}$$
$$\implies x=-4$$

Comment: What's the downvote for?!

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but i believe he may have downvoted because you provided the solution when OP asked for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A hint to get you started:

$$3^{x+2}\cdot 4^{-(x+3)}+3^{x+4}\cdot 4^{-(x+3)}=4^{-(x+3)}\cdot\left(3^{x+2}+3^{x+4}\right)=\frac{1}{4^{x+3}}\cdot\left(3^{x+3-1}+3^{x+3+1} \right)$$

Now try to factor out a term with $3^{(\ldots)}$ and see if you can apply some exponent laws.